# Redirect http://example.com to 123.123.123.123:8080 in windows

Tags: redirection, proxy

In Windows 7 how do we redirect hostnames to specific IP address AND port.

For example:

```
example.com   redirects to    123.123.123.123:8080
```

Note 1:

`C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts` can NOT redirect to a specific a port.

Note 2:

This thread:

> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/332651/forwarding-only-on-a-single-port-8080-to-localhost-windows-possible

refers to an app that is no longer available.

I tried privoxy but I am stuck, if someone can walk me through this.

Comment: I guess you're mixing redirection with hostnames definition. If you need redirection, ntg to do with OS but with your http server setup. For example in Apache, using mod_redirect directives. I do not about IIS if this is what you're using but pls look into your server setups.

Comment: You could look into a DNS/Reverse Proxy server that will take requests from example.com and redirect to your local IP/Port.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, even *Squid* is not capable of this, let alone *Privoxy*. You should do this with *IP Filters*, e.g. *iptables* on Linux (I really don't know what will do on Windows).

If you only demand it when you browsing web pages, there're extensions for Firefox and Chrome both called something like "Redirector".